# Html Canvas Resizing And Coordinate Space

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Note: I'm using Google Chrome

Currently I have this test page

http://www.evecakes.com/doodles/canvas_size_issue.htm

It **should** draw a rectangle right below the mouse cursor, but there are some really weird scaling issues which is causing it to draw at a varying offset. I think it's because the canvas coordinate space is not increasing along with its html size. Is there a way to increase that coordinate space size?

Here's the javascript function

```
$('#mapc').mousemove(function (event) {

            var canvas = $('#mapc');
            var ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d');

            ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
            ctx.fillRect(event.clientX, event.clientY, 55, 50);

            document.title = event.clientX + " --- " + event.clientY;

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `width` and `height` HTML attributes of the canvas. Right now, it's assuming its default width and the CSS is just stretching it, and it appears as if it is scaling.

A side-note, you can use `this` in the `mousemove` event - it is a reference to `#mapc` element, so you won't have to query the DOM on every mouse move.

```
var offset = $('#mapc').offset();

$('#mapc').mousemove(function (event) {

    var ctx = this.getContext('2d');

    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(200,0,0)";
    ctx.fillRect(event.pageX - offset.left, event.pageY - offset.top, 1, 1);
});
```